# APNS Acknowledgment

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I would like to know what are the possible way to identify whether our push messages are finally delivered from the APNS server.I already came up with some information as stated below

1. APNS is sending up the response codes of the acceptance of push request and possibly giving the error codes if any . for e.g.:If your payload is malfunctioned or device token is missing etc.
2. There are also a feedback service , with which you can check with and get to know what are  push messages or devices tokens, which APNS found it difficult to deliver the messages. for e.g.: Suppose your application is removed from your device etc.

Basically i would like to know how do we acknowledge a particular push message being delivered to the indented device.I greatly hope your views on my problems.

Thanks In Advance,
VishnuPrasad Kalathil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no delivery notification and APNS messages cannot be guaranteed to be delivered at all.

The only thing you could do is program your app to report itself once it receives a message to your server.

See this Apple guide on APNS https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1

[image]

Comment: Exactly, You can try other push notification services like Urban Airship, Amazon SNS Push and many more. which allows you to send a payload of more than 256bytes which in turn help you implement the idea suggested by Lee